# How do you find the type of event in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, events

Here is my HTML template:

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

Here is my TypeScript file:

```
onKey(event: any) {
    console.log(typeof event);
}
```

The `console.log` outputs `object` but in reality it should be `KeyboardEvent`.

Is there a generic way to find the type of event?

Answer (score 31):

You probably want to just check the `event.type` to see what it is, and infer the type from that.

Otherwise you could try using `event instanceof KeyboardEvent` or [user-defined type guards](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-defined-type-guard-functions).

Also, in your example you can just make the argument [`event:KeyboardEvent`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L3612) instead of `event:any`.

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla Actually, `KeyboardEvent` is an actual class so [it does work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBTAXIgogNwzCgEpEBvAWAChE7EZhFMGwBnKAQ0gziYGkMATwBGcTgCcAJgSKlEnADYYJUNACJBo8dPUkaAXxo0pcCCAC2cgHRipQ65ykzCxADIwORFRoiKYEADW6gA0yKj61KbmVsS2cPaOzrLunlDeEhqBwiAADqHhcCRAA).

Comment: You're right. The type is defined as an interface but it is actually a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). Sorry, I'll delete my answer then.