# In typescript, if you want to work with a DOM element, how should you go about declaring those properties to specify Typescript should allow them?

Tags: typescript, stimulusjs

QUESTION
In typescript, if you want to work with a DOM element that already has DOM properties, how should you go about declaring those properties to specify Typescript should allow them?

EXAMPLE
like `ondragstart` and `draggable` which are defined by the DOM

BACKGROUND

I have some drag & drop stuff going on using Stimulus written in Typescript. My implementation works in-browser, and it seems like Rails webpacker doesn't complain (Rails `6.0.3`) when its in development mode, but when it goes to compile the assets (`be rake assets:precompile`), I get these typescript errors.

Please bear in mind I am new to Typescript.

I think the problem is that Typescript does not know some things are native to the DOM implementation for HTML5 drag & drop (like properties `draggable`, `ondragstart`, etc). And in my `event` it doesn't like `dropEffect`. Maybe the type for `event` (which is `Event`) should be another subclass of `Event`

what am I doing wrong here? any help would be appreciated.

ERRORS

```
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts(31,18)
      TS2339: Property 'draggable' does not exist on type 'Element'.

ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
./app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts(32,18)
      TS2339: Property 'ondragstart' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

Both of these do exist as native HTML5 properties, but I suppose only on HTML5-supported browsers? Maybe my babel settings are too strict here?

the 'elemenet' comes from Stimulus

I want to tell Typescript I know these are both attributes on the native DOM elements and to allow them

```
ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
./app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts(40,5)
      TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: DragEvent) => any'.

ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
./app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts(41,5)
      TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: DragEvent) => any'.
```

not sure why I get this.

```
ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
./app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts(42,5)
      TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: DragEvent) => any'.

ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
./app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts(43,5)
      TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: DragEvent) => any'.
```

dropEffect

```
ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
./app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/jason/Work/xyz/app/javascript/controllers/audience/movable_pip_controller.ts(50,11)
      TS2339: Property 'dropEffect' does not exist on type 'Event'.
```

MY CODE (written in stimulus, compiled through the webpacker in Rails 6)

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";
import { polyfill } from "mobile-drag-drop";

// optional import of scroll behaviour
import { scrollBehaviourDragImageTranslateOverride } from "mobile-drag-drop/scroll-behaviour";

// options are optional ;)
polyfill({
  // use this to make use of the scroll behaviour
  dragImageTranslateOverride: scrollBehaviourDragImageTranslateOverride,
});

export default class MovablePipController extends Controller {
  static targets = [
    "pipComponent",
    "topLeft",
    "topRight",
    "bottomLeft",
    "bottomRight",
  ];

  private pipComponentTarget!: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private topLeftTarget!: HTMLElement;


  connect(): void {
    this.element.classList.add("bottom-right");

    this.element.draggable = true;
    this.element.ondragstart = this.onDragStart.bind(this);

    this.topLeftTarget.ondragenter = () => this.movePipTo("top-left");

    // prevent default is need to avoid interface glitches in touch envs
    this.topLeftTarget.ondragover = event.preventDefault();
    this.topRightTarget.ondragover = event.preventDefault();
    this.bottomLeftTarget.ondragover = event.preventDefault();
    this.bottomRightTarget.ondragover = event.preventDefault();

    // move pip to bottom-right upon load
    this.pipComponentTarget.dataset.corner = "bottom-right";
  }

  onDragStart(event: Event): void {
    event.dropEffect = "none";
  }

  movePipTo(corner: string): void {
    this.pipComponentTarget.dataset.corner = corner;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820248/how-do-you-find-the-type-of-event-in-typescript?

Comment: thank you @coli unfortunately that does not seem to explain it for me. I did try to understand it though but checking the type in javascript does not give the Typescript type definition does it?

Comment: `Property 'draggable' does not exist on type 'Element'` but it does exist on type `HTMLElement`, so you should use that instead. I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, though, so I don't know if you have control over this; at worst, you can use a type assertion, `(this.element as HTMLElement).draggable = true;` should work.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:
Use Stimulus targets to explicitly define the type of the parent object.

```
  connect(): void {
    this.element.draggable = true;
...
```

becomes

```
static targets = [
    "pipComponent",
  ];

  connect(): void {
    this.pipComponentTarget.draggable = true;
```